# Trying to make individual events editable in fullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to make individual events editable in fullCalendar.js based on a variable. Here's what I have:

```
editable: false,
eventRender: function(event){
  if (event.description && event.description.indexOf(pid) > -1){
    console.log(event.editable);
    console.log(event.resourceEditable);
    event.editable = true;
    event.resourceEditable = true;
    console.log(event.editable);
    console.log(event.resourceEditable);
  }
}
```

When I check the console log, both `editable` and `resourceEditable` are undefined before I set them, then after I set them they return as true. However I can't actually move them or drag them in the rendered calendar.

If I set `editable: true` I can manipulate the events. Adding the same eventRender function to make events uneditable doesn't work, either.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: eventRender runs _after_ fullCalendar has created a HTML element and is ready to place it onto the calendar. It's your chance to change the HTML, not the event object. Changes to the event object made at this time are ignored - fullCalendar considers that it has already finished processing that data. Note the full signature of [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) includes an `element` parameter which gives you access to that HTML. The only reason you have access to `event` here is so that you can access custom properties of your event and manipulate the HTML to include them.

Comment: if you want to make changes to the event object itself, such that those changes will be respected when the event is rendered, then use [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) instead, or even better, if you can, send the events from the server with the appropriate properties already set correctly.

Comment: @ADyson, awesome, I'll check this out, thanks so much!